# Android nested touch handling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch, swipe

I have a ViewPager inside a custom pager. Both swipe in horizontal direction. As I understood the Android touch model, my custom pager should monitor touch events going through onInterceptTouchEvent, checking for a swipe gesture and intercepting when one is detected, but also respect requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent so that if a child view should consume the same horizontal swipe gesture my custom view is monitoring for it is allowed to.

So far so good, my custom pager handles horizontal swipes well for non-scrolling or vertically scrolling child views and for horizontally scrolling child views, respects the disallow request so the child view can use the horizontal gesture.

However, if the horizontally scrolling child view has reached the end of its content so it cannot scroll any more, I would expect it to rescind its disallow request, so that the parent can intercept and consume the motion, but reading through the source (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java), I cannot see it ever calling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent with false argument, meaning once it has identified a gesture as a swipe, it will consume it regardless of whether it can actually make use of it or not.

Is my understanding of Android's touch handling system flawed, or are the standard view classes' touch handling too crude in this regard?

This is a question to improve my understanding of Android's touch handling model so I can work better *with* the system, not a request for workaround suggestions (though if the answer is authoritatively "the system does not allow for this", good workarounds are probably welcome to those who have a similar problem and find this question while searching)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ViewGroup.onNestedFling()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#onNestedFling(android.view.View,%20float,%20float,%20boolean))?

The pertinent excerpt from its documentation:

> If a nested scrolling child view would normally fling but it is at the edge of its own content, it can use this method to delegate the fling to its nested scrolling parent instead.